# How do we look up RequestID's thrown in AWS CloudFormation events which status reports CREATE_FAILED?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudtrail

Without setting up a CloudTrail and executing a CFN template which rolls back, I have started looking at Debugging options. I found [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-api-logging-cloudtrail.html) which says we can see the most recent without a created trail.

I tried to find RequestId documentation from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-guide&searchQuery=resourceid&this_doc_product=AWS+CloudFormation&facet_doc_product=AWS+CloudFormation) entering 'requested' in the search bar, which returned many unrelated items to my specific case (thanks for the attempt Kendra:).

I also have looked at cli docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-listing-event-history.html)

I guess I fist need to know what a RequestID is capable of helping me trace, as I am doing a simple debug of an instance I already know that has the wrong AMI ID for that region, but am trying. to re-familiarize myself. with fixing CFN templates after being out of the loop for a few years.

I'd like to know how someone else handles a CREATE _FAILED and ways to use the status reason in a verbose way. Each reason appears to be ';' separated, so even just a point in that direction might help weed through the mountain of information here. Thanks ahead of time- Rudy